# Row Value Comparison Alternatives?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm working in a C# SQLite library (SQLite-net) that doesn't seem to support row value comparisons like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (lastname, firstname) > ('Doe', 'John')
```

I get an error message at the first comma.  Is there a long form way of doing the same comparison that could be compatible with older SQLite implementations?  I'm no expert in SQL but I've tried a few ways of comparing the fields individually and in combination and haven't been able to figure it out.  Either records get included or excluded incorrectly.  I tried searching for an answer but I'm not sure how to formulate the question so I haven't found anything.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Sample data and expected results would probably help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two comparisons:

```
WHERE lastname > 'Doe' OR
      (lastname = 'Doe' AND firstname > 'John')
```

Some databases do support tuple comparisons, but older versions of SQLite did not.

Comment: Sqlite has supported [row value notation](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) since 3.15. OP is apparently using a really old version of the library.

Comment: Yes, it's an old library that hasn't been updated and may never be.  I just couldn't figure out how to do the same thing without the row value notation.  Thanks!

Comment: @shawn Exactly right.  I'm not even sure which version of SQLite is being used internally.